# Iteration of a text file in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio-2010

Ok, so I'm making a program that will read from a text file, convert each line into an array, the. Send each of those lines 1 per tick. This is in 2010 Visual Basic.
Closest I've gotten is sending all at once, I worked on it over night and am slowly destroying it.
Ideally, I want Button 1 click to populate the array from the file at LocationTB then start the timer.  The timer should send a line at a time on the GapTB interval.

```
Public Class Form1
Public TextLine As String
Public MyFileName As String
Public MyNewLine(1000) As String
Private Property z As Integer
Private Property objReader As Object


Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Dim Textline As String = ""
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = LocationTB.Text
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        MyFileName = LocationTB.Text
        FileOpen(1, MyFileName, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)
        z = 0

        Do Until EOF(1)
            MyNewLine(z) = LineInput(1)
            z = z + 1 
        Loop

        FileClose(1)
    End If

    Timer1.Interval = GapTB.Text
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        AppActivate(Hook.Text)
        SendKeys.Send(SimpleTB.Text)
        SendKeys.Send((Chr(13)))

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        For Each 
            TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine
            AppActivate(Hook.Text)
            SendKeys.Send(TextLine)
            SendKeys.Send((Chr(13)))
        Next

    Else

            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: -1, There really is an incredible amount of information available for text file operations on the internet. MSDN, Google etc will take you 5 seconds to find help on this. Plus, you didnt even ask a question, just gave some code.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to ask what I'm doing wrong, and if there is a better way to approach this.  I have been researching this in a number of places but am obviously not quite getting it.  If I'm completely off then I'll start again from scratch, but if I'm close I was looking for someone to point out my errors and offer any helpful suggestion.

Comment: If you are thinking of spamming or working an app or website so a human has to read or process computer generated or fraudulant output as if it were genuinely written by another person, you are wrong to be studying Computer Science. You need to study Theology. I suggest you start with hell and damnnation, then move on to the concept of divine retribution in the present life.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Not intending to make a spammer.  The program already works if I want it to be a spammer, but what I want is a timed Scripter. Related I suppose.  I want to be able to relay commands to another program and have a set of files to script it.  For example, when my other program runs and i have to put in 50+ commands for certain loadouts, I'd like to have that somewhat automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing  you're looking for?
It'll write the contents of a file (in this instance "C:\mark.txt") to the output window in Visual Studio.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private myTimer As Timer

    Private lines As String()
    Private currentLine As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\mark.txt")
        currentLine = 0

        myTimer = New Timer()

        AddHandler myTimer.Tick, AddressOf myTimer_Tick

        myTimer.Interval = 1000
        myTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If currentLine < lines.Count Then
            Dim lineToSend As String = lines(currentLine)
            Debug.Print(lineToSend)
            currentLine += 1
        Else
            myTimer.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

**Caveat**
The above code isn't scalable. If you're **SURE** the file will always be small then it will do (that said, they're *never always small*).

To make this scalable you'd need to hold the file open, and read each line as you need it, not load the entire file contents at once.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I modified that to fit it in with my code.  Its now outputting 2 lines at a time so I need to fix that, but it is iterating.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to consider using the My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\mark.txt") to get a StreamReader and then on the mytimer_Tick, call ReadLine rather than loading the memory with the entire file. Using a stream reader allows this to scale to large file sizes.

Comment: @Jim: I agree completely, however the code above is _simple_ enough to get things rolling. I'll add a note of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it to a application I started myself: Here's the code to make Calculator work:

```
   Dim ProcID As Integer
    ' Start the Calculator application, and store the process id.
    ProcID = Shell("CALC.EXE", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
    ' Activate the Calculator application.
    AppActivate(ProcID)
    ' Send the keystrokes to the Calculator application.
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("22", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("*", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("44", True)
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("=", True)
    ' The result is 22 * 44 = 968.
```

AppActivate should know the exact title of the form to activate. If not known, iterate the Processes to locate yours. If the title is correctly specified it should work